# Connect to Oracle Database and export data as CSV using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I want to connect oracle database to python and using select statement whatever result i will get, I want that result to be exported as csv file in sftp location.

I know we can connect oracle with python using cx_oracle package.

But my concern is to get data from oracle to csv and export that.

Also to make a note my data is bigger in size.

Can anyone help me to get the solution which could be fast as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to connect to the database? Do you know how to make a query? It's unclear at which step exactly you are having difficulty. Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: Yeah i know how would i connect to database. I am having trouble in exporting the result data (which i would get from select statement after using cursor.execute) directly as CSV.   Hope you get it..

Comment: Actually i have done the same thing with mysql and pandas. In that case using the cursor i was getting the result of query as pandas dataframe. And that dataframe we can export.

Comment: Can you show the working code you used for mysql and pandas, as well as the non-working code for Oracle?

Comment: cnx = pymysql.connect(host=, user=,password=,charset='utf8mb4',                      
                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursorObject = cnx.cursor()


df = pd.read_sql('select query' , cnx) # reading a table data from mysql

df.to_csv(path) # Exporting

Comment: Here I have connected mysql using pymysql.

after connecting getting query data in pandas dataframe.

and then exported as csv.


in my current case i dont want to bring any dataframe in the picture.
i just want to export query result to csv to my sftp path.

hope it is clear now....

Comment: Please [edit] the question, comments do not preserve the code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Start with something like this, and change to meet your requirements:

```
import csv
import os
import getpass

import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

sql = 'select * from employees'

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.arraysize = 5000
    with open("output.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile, lineterminator="\n")
        results = cursor.execute(sql)
        writer.writerows(results)
```

In particular, you will want to tune the `arraysize` value.

See [Tuning python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html).

Comment: Thanks Chris,  This is what I was looking for.  just out of curiosity can you elaborate if condition..

Comment: See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory