# Python connection to Oracle DB and then HOW TO export data as csv

Tags: python, import-csv

I am a student attempting to impart what I recently learned in an introduction to Python course at school into the workplace. I am trying to connect to an Oracle database (I only have read access) and then find some specific data and then export it to a csv file. Seems simple enough but what I learned in class is not working in the real world. I am asking not just for the answer but for a patient person to explain the why and how so I can learn. Thank you in advance:

Here is the updated code from the first reply:

```
import os
import csv
import oracledb

un = os.environ.get("myusername")
pw = os.environ.get("mypassword")
cs = os.environ.get("username/password@//hostname:port/servicename")

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.arraysize = 1000  # tune this for large queries
    f = open("emp.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    cursor.execute("""SELECT UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CTYPE, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RID, UT_ER.AM_CRI.PROB, UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT, UT_ER.AM_CRI.STATDESCR, UT_ER.AM_CRI.ACCTNUM, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CONNAME, UT_ER.AM_CRI.PHO, UT_ER.AM_CRI.STRADD, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CY, UT_ER.AM_CRI.SECLOC, UT_ER.AM_CRI.DATECR, UT_ER.AM_CRI.ASSNAM, UT_ER.AM_CRI.DATEMOD, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RESTIER1, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RESTIER2, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RES, UT_ER.AM_CRI.FIXQ, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CRDBY FROM UT_ER.AM_CRI WHERE UT_ER.AM_CRI.SITEID = '311' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.CATEG = 'Operations' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.TYP = 'Vendor' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.ITM = 'Bury Fiber' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT <> '1401' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT <> '1501' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT <> '1601' AND (UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP = 'SE - SAN - OPERATIONS FIBER REQUEST' OR UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP = 'SE - SAN - OPERATIONS FIBER BURY' OR UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP = 'VND - TANTRIC - OPERATIONS FIBER BURY')""")
    col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
    writer.writerow(col_names)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany()  # extra call at end won't incur extra round-trip
        if not rows:
            break
        writer.writerows(rows)
    f.close()
```

Here is the NEW AND UPDATED code from the most recent reply:

```
import os
import csv
import getpass

import oracledb

un = "usernamehere"
pw = getpass.getpass("passwordhere")
cs = "hostname:port/servicename"

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.arraysize = 1  # tune this for large queries
    f = open("emp.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    cursor.execute("""SELECT UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CTYPE, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RID, UT_ER.AM_CRI.PROB, UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT, UT_ER.AM_CRI.STATDESCR, UT_ER.AM_CRI.ACCTNUM, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CONNAME, UT_ER.AM_CRI.PHO, UT_ER.AM_CRI.STRADD, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CY, UT_ER.AM_CRI.SECLOC, UT_ER.AM_CRI.DATECR, UT_ER.AM_CRI.ASSNAM, UT_ER.AM_CRI.DATEMOD, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RESTIER1, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RESTIER2, UT_ER.AM_CRI.RES, UT_ER.AM_CRI.FIXQ, UT_ER.AM_CRI.CRDBY FROM UT_ER.AM_CRI WHERE UT_ER.AM_CRI.SITEID = '311' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.CATEG = 'Operations' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.TYP = 'Vendor' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.ITM = 'Bury Fiber' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT <> '1401' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT <> '1501' AND UT_ER.AM_CRI.STAT <> '1601' AND (UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP = 'SE - SAN - OPERATIONS FIBER REQUEST' OR UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP = 'SE - SAN - OPERATIONS FIBER BURY' OR UT_ER.AM_CRI.GROUP = 'VND - TANTRIC - OPERATIONS FIBER BURY')""")
    col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
    writer.writerow(col_names)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany()  # extra call at end won't incur extra round-trip
        if not rows:
            break
        writer.writerows(rows)
    f.close()
```

Now where I need help is the export to the csv file. In class I was able to do this but it was a simple db with just one table and a few rows and since then I have lost what it was that I used to make that work. I have tried google and it led me to a post I think is close [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68843894/connect-to-oracle-database-and-export-data-as-csv-using-python), but I just don't understand what all is going on there. Thank you.

Here is that new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\Remedy_SQL_Connection\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 1013, in connect
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 135, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 317, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src\oracledb\impl/base/connect_params.pyx", line 182, in oracledb.base_impl.ConnectParamsImpl._check_credentials
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\oracledb\errors.py", line 111, in _raise_err
    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4001: no credentials specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  It uses the latest version of cx_Oracle [which is now called python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  Or you can use the answer given in the question you linked to.  Try one of the solutions and then update your question with the code you tried and explain what problems you still have.

```
import os
import csv
import getpass

import oracledb

#un = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
#pw = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
#cs = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING")

un = "chris"
pw = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
cs = "hostname:port/servicename"

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.arraysize = 1000  # tune this for large queries
    f = open("emp.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    cursor.execute("""select * from emp""")
    col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
    writer.writerow(col_names)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany()  # extra call at end won't incur extra round-trip
        if not rows:
            break
        writer.writerows(rows)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Sorry so long on the reply, I only get to work on this on Mondays and Fridays. I updated the code in my initial post with what you gave me and it produces this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\Remedy_SQL_Connection\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import oracledb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oracledb'

Please advise how I should proceed and thank you.

Comment: Ignore that last post, I added oracledb through pip and now I get a much different error that I am adding to the original post above:

Comment: `cs` should end up being a variable containing a string like `hostname:port/servicename` since you already pass the username and password as separate parameters.   The `os.environ.get()` calls should reference the names of environment variables.  You can then set these variables in the shell before you start Python.  I'll update my answer to prompt from the console, which might be easier for you.

Comment: Part 1: Sorry so long on the reply, it has been a very busy week. I updated my code to yours and when I run it I get the box down below, titled 'main', that pops up and where there would normally be some type of error in it or some data that was retrieved, it is instead just blank and empty (obviously it has the whit texted file path stuff that is always there but other than that it is blank). It just stays empty for forever. I hit run and went to lunch and came back and it was still empty. I set the arraysize to 1 as well hoping to get anything at all back and it didn't change the outcome...

Comment: Part 2: When I press the X to close that window out it says Process 'main' is running. "Do you want to terminate the process 'main'? My options to select are Terminate, Disconnect and Cancel. I hit terminate and the window closes. i can find no csv files in the appropriate directories and nothin else opens up. Please advise and thank you for your time.

Comment: Bueller? Bueller? Bueller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to my issue. Am I doing something wrong?